# Need to increase arrow size and the text size

Tags: tikz-pgf

With code, I am able generate the following figure.

I don't know, how to increase the arrow size and the text size.

I want to keep the figure size same. Only the arrow size and text size need to be increased to a size which looks neat and easy to read.

[image]

THE CODE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=50]{standalone}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw [dashed, thick] circle [radius=4];
  \draw [line width=1.0pt] (-18,-12) -- (18,-12) -- (18,12) -- (-18,12) -- (-18,-12);


    \foreach \x in {18}{
        \foreach \y in {-12,-11,...,12}{
        \draw[line width=0.8pt] [->] ([xshift=\x cm]0.0,\y cm) -- ([xshift=\x cm]2.0,\y cm);
        }
    }
    \foreach \x in {-18}{
        \foreach \y in {-12,-11,...,12}{
        \draw[line width=0.8pt] [->] ([xshift=\x cm]0.0,\y cm) -- ([xshift=\x cm]-2.0,\y cm);
        }
    }

    \path (22,0) node {$\sigma^{\infty}_{x}$};
    \path (-22,0) node {$\sigma^{\infty}_{x}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that you can format code as code by indenting it by 4 spaces (easy way: highlight the code and press the '{}' button).

Comment: Thank you. I will do that next time. I always wondered how display of CODE was not good but someone would edit it, it looks awesome!

Comment: How big do you want the figure? Size?

Answer (score 6):

Use `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` (instead of `arrows`) and put this as the option to `tikzpicture`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[> = {Latex[scale=2.5]},font=\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont]
```

Change font size and `scale` as you wish. But ensure that the font is scalable, it is better to use `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=50]{standalone}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[> = {Latex[scale=2.5]},font=\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont]
\draw [dashed, thick] circle [radius=4];
  \draw [line width=1.0pt] (-18,-12) -- (18,-12) -- (18,12) -- (-18,12) -- (-18,-12);


    \foreach \x in {18}{
        \foreach \y in {-12,-11,...,12}{
        \draw[line width=0.8pt] [->] ([xshift=\x cm]0.0,\y cm) -- ([xshift=\x cm]2.0,\y cm);
        }
    }
    \foreach \x in {-18}{
        \foreach \y in {-12,-11,...,12}{
        \draw[line width=0.8pt] [->] ([xshift=\x cm]0.0,\y cm) -- ([xshift=\x cm]-2.0,\y cm);
        }
    }

    \path (22,0) node {$\sigma^{\infty}_{x}$};
    \path (-22,0) node {$\sigma^{\infty}_{x}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get the following ERROR message.                                I can't find file `tikzlibraryarrows.meta.code.tex' \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

Comment: @ltxEnthu You will need `tikz` version 3. Which version is yours? Please update.

Comment: How do I find that out? Which is my Tikz version?

Comment: @ltxEnthu Add `\listfiles`, say before `\documentclass{..}` and your log file (at the end, under `*File List*` heading) will have the details.